# Is there any Youtube API for sharing private videos to gmail users?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

There's an API to upload or update video on Youtube, with different video privacy state using `status.privacyStatus` param. But is there API / API params to share the private video to some Gmail users?

The same feature is available over the web here
[image]

The upload video API is in here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource